# What makes eOS save the layout of workspaces and apps between docking and undocking a laptop? (using multiple monitors)

Tags: pantheon

For some reason, elementaryOS is the only Linux distro that remembers the location of applications when docking and undocking, when using multiple monitors.

Pantheon does this, every other desktop environment that I've tried does not.